# Magento2 how to display only special price of product

Tags: magento2, special-price

How to display only special price of product if it contains else it should not display

Comment: You mean like this ? => $15.00 Regular Price $34.00 or $15?

Comment: Rohan Hapani $15 is special price means only $15  should display

Comment: Please accept and upvote answer if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `final_price.phtml` from

> Vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

to

> Vendor/theme/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Find this code : `<span class="old-price"></span>`

This span is used for display old price when special price is available. You can remove it in your custom theme file if you don't want to display.